# Add __wrap prefix to mocked functions with Cmock

Tags: unit-testing, ceedling, cmock

I have generated `mock_foo.h` and `mock_foo.c` from my `foo.h` header using Ceedling. The problem is that in generated file there are function names the same as in `foo.c`. For example, `foo_function()` is now in both `foo.c` and `mock_foo.c`, and I have to manually add `__wrap` prefix so that linker doesn't complain about multiple definitions.

Is it possible to add some option in `project.yml` in order to generate function which already have that prefix, ie. `__wrap_foo_function()`?

Comment: Why do you want to include `foo.c` and `mock_foo.c` in your project at the same time? The basic idea of a mock is to replace the original module, i.e. to replace `foo.c` with `mock_foo.c`. That's why the identical function names make sense.

Comment: The build system I'm using sees both files. It's a common problem, you can check [this](https://blog.microjoe.org/2017/unit-tests-c-cmocka-coverage-cmake.html#system-call-mocking-with-wrap) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMock has currently no option to add a user-defined prefix (like `__wrap`) to function names. Such a feature has been discussed twice back in 2014 (see [Issue #32](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/CMock/issues/32)) and 2017 ([Issue #137](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/CMock/issues/137)), but unfortunately the discussion dried out too early to add the feature to the project.

[Issue #32](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/CMock/issues/32) even proposed a patch but I guess this will not be easily applicable anymore to the current code basis.

A possible workaround might be to write a script that generates a modified version of the modules header file `foo.h` by adding the `__wrap` prefix to all function declarations within the file. With such a modified header CMock would generate a `mock_foo.c` with the appropriate function names.

For Python exists the [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser) project which might be helpful for this task. Especially the [func_defs.py](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/examples/func_defs.py) example looks like a promising starting point.